# find a regular expression for a given language

Tags: regular-expressions

It is given that $\Sigma=\{1,2,4,5,7,9\}$ and
$L=\{w: w \in \Sigma^{*} \text{ ,w gets divided completely by }5\}$.
Could you help me to find a regular expression for this language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If something is divisible by 5 then it ends in zero or five.

So (1|2|4|5|7|9)*5 would characterize your language.

Comment: I have also an other question..if the language was $L=\{w: w \in \Sigma^{*} \text{ ,w as a decimal,gets divided completely by }5\}$ ,would the regular expression be the same?

Comment: I don't know what "as a decimal" means...other than restricting your alphabet to 10 digits.

Comment: Yes,it is meant that $w$ consists digits between 0 and 9..So,it is the same regular expression.or not??

Comment: Yes, then it is that same regex because you are also restricted to $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma$ doesn't have any characters that are not digits.  If $\Sigma$ had non-digit characters, then it wouldn't have been the same.

Comment: Nice...Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: And something else..if $w$ should get divided completely by 7,then the regular expression wouldn't be like that: $(1|2|4|5|7|9)^{*}7$,right??Because,for example $297$ doesn't get divided completely by 7..But,what can I change then at the regular expression?

Comment: @evinda If you want a regex for divisibility by seven, look here: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3503/hard-code-golf-regex-for-divisibility-by-7  If you want a simpler state machine for divisibility by seven (using modular arithmetic to represent multiple states as a single integer) then look here : http://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/10005.5.shtml  If you need help with the code for the non regex version, post a question to stack overflow and leave a link here, and I will answer it.

Comment: Isn't there a simpler regular expression for the language??

Comment: Looks simple to me.